# r: ggplot2 correlation plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I'm trying to create a correlation plot based off two parameters in my data frame.. However I'm confused on how to manipulate the data frame to get what I want.

**This is the structure of my data frame:**

```
structure(list(orgid = c("USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ"), locid = c("USGS-01367785", 
"USGS-01367785", "USGS-01455099", "USGS-01455099", "USGS-01440000", 
"USGS-01440000", "USGS-01380100", "USGS-01380100", "USGS-01380100", 
"USGS-01387700", "USGS-01387700", "USGS-01398000", "USGS-01398000", 
"USGS-0140940950", "USGS-01466500", "USGS-01461880", "USGS-01461880", 
"USGS-01445600", "USGS-01446400", "USGS-0140940950"), stdate = structure(c(16134, 
16134, 16133, 16133, 16135, 16135, 16133, 16133, 16133, 16127, 
16127, 16105, 16105, 16112, 15770, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15762, 
16112), class = "Date"), sttime = structure(c(45000, 45000, 39600, 
39600, 35040, 35040, 48000, 48000, 48000, 39600, 39600, 38700, 
38700, 39600, 37200, 32400, 32400, 40500, 36000, 39600), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), charnam = c("Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Specific conductance", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
"Total dissolved solids"), val = c(0.21, 154, 0.43, 333, 0.16, 
109, 12.1, 0.2, 143, 32, 0.05, 1.03, 711, 1.62, 31, 218, 391, 
384, 478, 104), valunit = c("tons/ac ft", "mg/l", "tons/ac ft", 
"mg/l", "tons/ac ft", "mg/l", "tons/day", "tons/ac ft", "mg/l", 
"mg/l", "tons/ac ft", "tons/ac ft", "mg/l", "tons/day", "uS/cm @25C", 
"mg/l", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "mg/l"), swqs = c("FW2-NT", 
"FW2-NT", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TM", "FW2-TM", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", 
"FW2-NT", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "PL", "FW1", 
"FW2-TM", "FW2-TM", "FW2-NT", "FW2-TM", "PL"), WMA = c(2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 14L, 19L, 11L, 11L, 
1L, 1L, 14L), year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L)), .Names = c("orgid", "locid", 
"stdate", "sttime", "charnam", "val", "valunit", "swqs", "WMA", 
"year"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want to plot Total dissolved solids vs. Specific conductance.. However the values of each these parameters are all in one column named val. Would I have to manipulate the data frame to have Total dissolved solids in its own column with it's values and the same for Specific conductance? If so, how would I be able to do that based on how the charnam column has the names of the parameters and the column val has all the values of the parameters? I tried subsetting the data frame but it's not working.

**Code I have:**

```
correlation_plot1<-ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=TDS_correlation_df,aes(x="",y=val))+
  geom_point(data=SC_correlation_df,aes(x=val,y=""))+
  ggtitle("Statewide Total Dissolved Solids vs. Specific Conductance Correlation\n;1997-2018") +
  xlab("SC(µS/cm)") + ylab("TDS(mg/L)")+
  scale_color_manual("",
                     values = c("red"),
                     labels=c("Freshwater Aquatic Life Criteria for TDS = 500 mg/L"))+

  correlation_theme+

  theme(legend.position ="bottom")
```

TDS_correlation and Sc_correlation are subsets of the original data set, filtered to only have that parameter.

Comment: 1. it's not clear which column are used for identification of each sample (to match the 2 measurements). 2. you should probably look at `tidyr::spread`

Comment: @agenis the column charnam says what parameter it is and the column val has the value of the parameter..

Comment: @KWANGER as agenis already commented which `val`'s belong together? try this to see the problem `library(tidyverse);
d %>% 
  select(charnam, val) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  spread(charnam, val)`

Comment: @Jimbou the first charnam goes with the first val etc.

Comment: To be more concrete: The first `val = 0.21` of `"Total dissolved solids"` belongs to which `val = x` of `"Specific conductance"`? When your answer is no idea then use this instead `ggplot(data, aes(charnam, val)) + 
  geom_boxplot()`

Comment: @KWANGER, I get what you're trying to do, the issue is that when you `spread` the data you're left with NA values.  You need another column identifying each group as a pair.  The only way I can think of working with this is breaking them apart and then joining them back together with a `left_join`.

Comment: @Jimbou I'm completely confused on what you mean.

Comment: @BenG  yes that is exactly the problem.. So when you say break them apart and join them back together.. Do you mean the original dataset?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is very clunky, but I believe it gets to what you're looking for.  As the comments discuss, the issue isn't with your `ggplot` code, but with your data:

```
data <- structure(list(orgid = c("USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ"), locid = c("USGS-01367785", 
"USGS-01367785", "USGS-01455099", "USGS-01455099", "USGS-01440000", 
"USGS-01440000", "USGS-01380100", "USGS-01380100", "USGS-01380100", 
"USGS-01387700", "USGS-01387700", "USGS-01398000", "USGS-01398000", 
"USGS-0140940950", "USGS-01466500", "USGS-01461880", "USGS-01461880", 
"USGS-01445600", "USGS-01446400", "USGS-0140940950"), stdate = structure(c(16134, 
16134, 16133, 16133, 16135, 16135, 16133, 16133, 16133, 16127, 
16127, 16105, 16105, 16112, 15770, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15762, 
16112), class = "Date"), sttime = structure(c(45000, 45000, 39600, 
39600, 35040, 35040, 48000, 48000, 48000, 39600, 39600, 38700, 
38700, 39600, 37200, 32400, 32400, 40500, 36000, 39600), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), charnam = c("Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Specific conductance", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
"Total dissolved solids"), val = c(0.21, 154, 0.43, 333, 0.16, 
109, 12.1, 0.2, 143, 32, 0.05, 1.03, 711, 1.62, 31, 218, 391, 
384, 478, 104), valunit = c("tons/ac ft", "mg/l", "tons/ac ft", 
"mg/l", "tons/ac ft", "mg/l", "tons/day", "tons/ac ft", "mg/l", 
"mg/l", "tons/ac ft", "tons/ac ft", "mg/l", "tons/day", "uS/cm @25C", 
"mg/l", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "mg/l"), swqs = c("FW2-NT", 
"FW2-NT", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TM", "FW2-TM", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", 
"FW2-NT", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "PL", "FW1", 
"FW2-TM", "FW2-TM", "FW2-NT", "FW2-TM", "PL"), WMA = c(2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 14L, 19L, 11L, 11L, 
1L, 1L, 14L), year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L)), .Names = c("orgid", "locid", 
"stdate", "sttime", "charnam", "val", "valunit", "swqs", "WMA", 
"year"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)

data_tidy <- data %>%
 spread(charnam, val)

specific_conductance <- data_tidy %>%
 select(`Specific conductance`) %>%
 filter(!is.na(`Specific conductance`) == T) %>%
 rep(times = 4) %>%
 as.data.frame() %>%
 gather(1:4) %>%
 select(value) %>%
 rename("Specific conductance" = value) %>%
 rowid_to_column()

total_dissolved_solids <- data_tidy %>%
 select(`Total dissolved solids`) %>%
 filter(!is.na(`Total dissolved solids`) == T) %>%
 rowid_to_column()

combined <- total_dissolved_solids %>%
 left_join(specific_conductance)

ggplot(combined, aes(x = `Specific conductance`, y = `Total dissolved solids`)) +
 geom_point()
```

Comment: Please check also the different `valunit`'s and timepoints (`stdate` & `sttime`). Before these and the issuse above are not cleared, it is not a good idea to give the OP an answer as it is statistically as well as mathematically completely rubbish.

Comment: @Jimbou, I'm going to respectfully disagree.  The OP's questions was about `ggplot`.  I think we can give him the benefit of the doubt as to methodolgical integrety of whatever underlying analysis he/she is trying to achieve.

Comment: @BenG Thanks , sorry for not being clear as I'm new to using R and I'm still learning.. This answer however is not working. When I try and run the first part data_tidy I get this error: Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows .. with a whole list of rows

Comment: @KWANGER I edited it so its explicit for creating the original object from your data.  Also, make sure the `tidyverse` package is installed.

Comment: @BenG I'm still getting the same error.. not sure why

Comment: @BenG do you have any idea why?

Comment: @KWANGER try starting a new R session and/or clearing all objects from your workspace.  Try copying a pasting the code exactly as it is here into https://rdrr.io/snippets/ . . . looks like it's working.

Comment: @BenG weird.. it works on when I run it in the link you provided but even when I start a new R session and clear all objects it's giving me that error... That  is exactly what I want tho!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176159/discussion-between-ben-g-and-kwanger).